# Completely remove OpenVAS data

Tags: apt, package-management, openvas

On my Ubuntu 18.04 I discovered /var/lib/openvas/ which occupies almost 2 GB. I believe I tried OpenVAS long time ago and this data has left. Now trying to remove it, I reinstalled OpenVAS as Ubuntu package and purged it. I verified that no OpenVAS package remains installed. Still the folder is there. I could delete it manually but I would prefer a more clean approach instead. How to remove OpenVAS entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could delete it manually but I would prefer a more clean approach instead.

Why?

> How to remove OpenVAS entirely?

Manually delete it. That directory you created yourself when you set openvas up so it is not part of the installation process so will not be deleted or purged by the system. It contains certificates in ./CA and ./public/CA).

Comment: I thought that maybe other data in other places of my file system exists and that those data is deleted too when using an automatic deletion. But if there isn't any such process, I have to delete that folder manually. Are there other locations on my filesystem where OpenVAS may have stored data too?

Comment: after you deleted it do a `sudo locatedb` and then `locate openvas` and it should return zero results